# Content blured in Silverlight4 after making a rotation and a scale

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

Hy,
I am making a rotation of 180 degree and after that a scale of -1 on X axis. This is applied to the main grid of the user control.
In this grid i have  a button and a stack panel with textBox.
The problem is that after the animation is done the button and the textBox become blurred.

If someone can help, i wait an answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem looks to be at the rotation of the projection. If is set to 0 the blur disappeared. The solution was to set the rotation on 0 and make some other modification at the end of the animation